# Infinite Full Crawl

Tags: search, crawl

My current full crawl has been running for over 200 hours and I'm worried that this will go on to infinity. The net size of all databases on the SQL server is around 25GB.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enough disk space on the drive where your search index is stored.

Comment: Hi HarryB, How do I find where the search index is stored?

Comment: Please use this PoweShell command: $ssa = Get-SPServiceApplication –Name 
“Search Service Application”
$active = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology 
-SearchApplication $ssa -Active
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $active

Comment: It is stored here by default: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Applications

Comment: Hi @MHeld, how do you change where it is stored?

Comment: @HarryB, what is it that that command does?

Comment: That command is for finding the index location

Comment: Please update your answer with more details to make it really helpful

Comment: @HarryB, that command isn't working for me: 'A positional error cannot be found that accepts argument '='.'

Comment: have you figured out if the disk space is indeed the issue? I had the same issue with the crawl going on for months and the disk space was the issue. I added more disk space and restared the server. Search worked fine after that.

Comment: @HarryB, I've taken over an SP implementation on which the search was broken. I deleted that search and created a new one. If the default location for a new search is the 'C' drive then there is insufficient space. However there is a partition on the VM called 'Search' with plenty of space, I would like to move the data there.

Comment: Please have a look ath this artilce as a starting point to reconfigure search:http://consulting.risualblogs.com/blog/2013/09/03/sharepoint-2013move-the-search-index-location/comment-page-1/

Comment: @HarryB, There is plenty of space where the search index is - nearly 200GB and it's sitting in it's own partition with nothing else to eat up that space. So it's not a disk space issue - any other ideas?

Comment: is your crawl still having the same issue?

Comment: @HarryB, Yes, I've restarted it but it still seems to be going on infinitely.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the index, restarting the server, checking permssions for the search crawl account, checking crawl log etc? I would also suggest going though the ULS logs to get some more clues about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to stop the hanging full crawl via CentralAdministration. Very often it then is stuck in status "Stopping". Try to restart the Search-related Services in the Windows-Services console. If this doesn't help, try to restart the SharePoint-Server on which Search resides.

After a forced stop of a hanging crawl, the index-partition gets degraded in some cases (marked with a yellow triangle in CentralAdministration). This can be fixed in most cases by performing an Index-Reset. You have to perform another Full Crawl after an Index-Reset to get your Search-Results back.

Comment: thanks for this. It does seem to be stuck in 'Stopping' status. Is there a given time interval that I should wait before accepting that it is stuck? How long should stopping a full crawl normally take?

Comment: Actually the full crawl has now stopped, the status has now changed to 'idle'. What's to stop the infinite full crawl from happening again though? Have you any idea what could cause the infinite full crawl?

Comment: Try to execute the full crawl again. It sometimes happens without any reason you should care about. If it stucks again, you should dig in Windows Eventviewer and SharePoint ULS-Logs.

Comment: I have restarted the crawl, it's now been going on for over 25 hours and I'm anticipating much the same as before. I have Windows Event Viewer open - what am I looking for? Also, I can't find the SharePoint Logs, there is no `Logs` subfolder in the `C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14` folder.

Comment: Look for SharePoint Search related Errors in Windows Eventviewer -> Windows Logs -> Application -> Level: Error and Critical. Use ULS-Viewer to analyze SharePoint ULS-Logs: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020